# Check if multiple dictionary keys are located in a string

Tags: python, loops

Imagine having a txt file with like

```
5843092xxx289421xxx832175xxx...
```

You have a dictionary with keys correspoding to letters
A am trying to search for each key within the string to output a message.

```
decoder = {5843092:'a', 289421:'b'}

with open( "code.txt","r") as fileTxt:
    fileTxt = fileTxt.readlines()

b = []
for key in decoder.keys():
    if key in fileTxt:
        b.append(decoder[key])
print(b)
```

this is what I have I feel like im on the right track but I am missing how to do each iteration maybe?

the goal output in this i.e. would be either a list or string of `ab...`

Comment: Is the data file all one line like you have it here? What does `xxx` represent?

Comment: You didn't explain what is wrong with your code.

Comment: my code is wrong because I only print b as it is before the loops. the xxx is actual letters in a .txt file in between the "coded message numbers"

Comment: it is not in one line because when i split("xxx") I receive a list that has some line breaks (\n) i.e. ['596029', '36267\n590467', 547892, ...]

Comment: If the text contained 584309289421 (i.e. overlapping keys), would you want to consider that it has `a` and `b` or just  one of them or neither ? (your code currently finds them both).  Also, do you expect each key to only be present once in the text or would you expect to output the same letter as many times as the key is present ?

Comment: I would want to consider that it has a and b, my actual dictionary is much longer and has many letters as the value to keys of various number "codes". so it would be each time it is present as in there would be more than one iteration of it in the txt

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You have a list of strings, and you're treating it as if it's one string.
2. You're building your output based on the order the keys appear in the decoder dictionary, rather than the order they appear in the input text.  That means the message will be all scrambled.

If the input text actually separates each key with a fixed string like `xxx`, the straightforward solution is to split on that string:

```
for line in fileTxt:
    print(' '.join(decoder.get(int(key), '?') for key in line.split('xxx')))
```